# uiscrollview framesize iphone 4inc and 3.5 inc

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am using two uiscrollview in my controllerview like this picture;

[image]

But I have a problem with frame resize when I run the application. I added constraints for all components. But when I run the application on iphone 3.5 inc, it is look like this picture;

[image]

How can I fix it? I want to looks like How I design.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check your constraints, basically your bottom side of first page controll like center of your view and fix all other object with this

Comment: I added a Align center y constraint for upper page control, and fixed. thanks